# How to decide the scope of the following lambda expression?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am having a difficulty in deciding the scope of the left-most lambda in the following expression.

```
λx.x(λuv.v)(λab.a)(λcd.c)
```

I have learnt that we should put brackets in such a way that the scope of lambda will be maximum. So arrived at candidate- answer 1, below.

On the other hand, since the expression `(λuv.v)(λab.a)(λcd.c)` does not contain any x, if we put brackets as in answer 2, still we are not changing the scope, right?

But I know that these two answers are not equivalent. So which one is the correct one?

The two candidate answers are:

1. `λx.(x(λuv.v)(λab.a)(λcd.c))`
2. `(λx.x)(λuv.v)(λab.a)(λcd.c)`

I came up with this confusion through the tutorial: [A Tutorial Introduction to the Lambda Calculus by Raul Rojas](http://www.utdallas.edu/~gupta/courses/apl/lambda.pdf). There, in page 6, ~T is given as `λx.x(λuv.v)(λab.a)(λcd.c)`. If we apply brackets as in my answer-1, we will not be able to evaluate ~T to F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is:

> (λx.x (λuv.v) (λab.a) (λcd.c))

If I add in parethenese to disambiguate application, it becomes.

> (λx.((x (λuv.v)) (λab.a)) (λcd.c))

Answer (score 1):

Sorry reviving this question, but I think there are parenthesis missing on the tutorial. It should be

$$\neg T = (\lambda x. x (\lambda uv. v)(\lambda ab. a))(\lambda cd. c)$$

On the book we have
$$\neg T = \lambda x. x (\lambda uv. v)(\lambda ab. a)(\lambda cd. c)$$
but that will evaluate to $T$ as the first redex to be processed will be $(\lambda uv. v)(\lambda ab. a)$

I'm a newbie here, so veterans, please check if I'm not mistaken!