# Which redexes are there in $\lambda s. \lambda z. (\lambda u. z)(\lambda v. v)$? How to substitute arguments?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm having difficulties understanding lambda calculus, specially identifying what's a redex. Which redexes are there in $\lambda s. \lambda z. (\lambda u. z)(\lambda v. v)$?

The book uses
$(\lambda u. z) [u \to (\lambda v. v)]$,

but isn't $(\lambda s. \lambda z. (\lambda u. z))[s \to (\lambda v. v)]$ valid too?

Answer (score 1):

You must learn how to put in parentheses and then it will be easier to figure out what is what. In the above case, we first put in parentheses:
$$\lambda s . (\lambda z . ((\lambda u. z) (\lambda v . v))).$$
This is the only correct way to put back parentheses. For instance, this is wrong
$$(\lambda s . (\lambda z . (\lambda u . z))) (\lambda v . v)$$
Why is it wrong? Because the rules for writing expressions without parentheses say that when you see $\lambda x . \cdots$ that means that $\lambda x$ binds the whole expression. For instance $\lambda x . x (\lambda y . y)$ is the same as $\lambda x . (x (\lambda y . y))$ and is *diffrerent* from $(\lambda x . x) (\lambda y . y)$.

If this is not resolving your dilemma you have to explain *why* you think that the other redex is valid.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Quick question: when I apply a parameter to a function, should I insert it parenthesized? Say I have $\text{f}=\lambda n. \lambda s. \lambda z. n (\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))$, and I want to evaluate $\text{f} c_0$, with $c_0=\lambda a. \lambda b. b$. Does it become $\lambda s. \lambda z. \lambda a. \lambda b. b (\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))$ or $\lambda s. \lambda z. (\lambda a. \lambda b. b) (\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))$?

Comment: You should parenthesize everything in sight until the day when you understand which things need not be parenthesized.

Comment: Yes, I'm inserting parenthesis everywhere now, but could you please answer the question on the previous comment? It does make a difference to parenthesize the parameter in that case, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you should patenthesize the argument, unless it is a single letter or already paranthesized.

Comment: Alright, so I think I got lambda calculus now... thanks so much for the help! If you'd be so kind, I even tried to answer a question that I think someone answered it wrong, could you take a quick glance? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12740/how-to-decide-the-scope-of-the-following-lambda-expression/14193#14193